# How does data reach peripherals in STM32H7xx?

Tags: stm32, embedded, memory, bus, peripheral

I'm trying to understand bus interconnection matrix in stm32h7xx. Here is a capture of the H753's one:

[image]

In particular, I'm wondering how a data buffer located in DTCM would reach the SPI1's tx register. From the figure above, I imagine data would be read by the CPU from DTCM and transmit to AXI SRAM through L1-Cache (provided cache is enabled). Then, how does it continue its way to the SPI registers?

I believe SPI1 is a Domain-D2 peripheral, in particular, APB2, as per the table below:

[image]

So, it would travel through the D1-to-D2 AHB bus and then what? The only connection I see to APB2 is through SRAM1, 2, or 3, or AHB1. Does the data get to APB2 to one of these "bus interconnections"? Is it written in SRAM temporarily?

(Images obtained from the [stm32h742/43/53/50 reference manual](https://file:///home/danielgo/Downloads/rm0433-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Probably through AHBP. Peripheral accesses are not cached as the register values are likely to change due to normal operation of the peripheral. Unlikely to be temporarily stored into an intermediate ram location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two paths from D1 domain to D2 domain.

1. Blue path: (AHBP) Data comes directly from the Cortex M7 microprocessor.
2. Red path: (AXIM) Data comes from the L1 cache

There is one path the other way.
Green path: The data is transferred from the peripheral to the L1 cache (AXIM).

In the D2 domain:
There are several outbound paths for AHBP data and AXIM data indicated by coloured dots on the multiplexers in the matrix. Generally the peripheral data shares the DMA memory path.
There is also a path through AHB1 to both APB1/2.

The data returning to the M7 travels to the DMA memory path but The multiplexer diverts The data to the D2-D1 AHB bus as shown by the green colouration.

[image]

Comment: Then, there are multiplexers that 'route' the traffic? Kind of what a network router does? So there are not temporary copies? Having that the green path is longer, is it reasonable to assume that writes will be faster than reads? (from the M7 point of view)

Comment: @Martel:"Then, there are multiplexers ". Yes as indicated on the diagram that you posted. The router is very specialized and optimized for throughput. There are no temporary copies en-route. That would just slow things down. Data travelling through the L1 cache will have a temporary copy to allow bus synchronizing. The diagram demonstrates functionality, not physical implementation.  The path lengths may be very similar. The data sheets will provide all the timing information regarding read and write timing, usually in number of clock cycles.